# How can I return a text error message in IIS-hosted WCF service for all responses which are not HTTP 200?

Tags: wcf

I am writing a WCF service which will be hosted in IIS over HTTP. I wish for all responses which are not HTTP 200 (e.g., 404, 500) to have a Content-Type of `text/plain` and the response body a text message.

How can I achieve this?